# Displaying form on first login

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm trying to work out how I can display a form to a user upon their first login to my app ( to fill in profile information) after which they can proceed to the regular site.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: try usewebstorage or cookies, this will allow you achieve your goal, unless the user clear the cookies or delete the localstorage. read about localstorage here https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Answer (score 2):

You can make the trick using app startup script:
https://devsite.googleplex.com/appmaker/settings#app_start

Assuming that you have Profile model/datasource, code in your startup script will look similar to this:

```js
loader.suspendLoad();

var profileDs = app.datasources.Profile;

// It would be more secure to move this filtering to the server side
profileDs.query.filters.UserEmail._equals = app.user.email;

profileDs.load({
  success: function() {
    if (profileDs.item === null) {
       app.showPage(app.pages.CreateProfile);
    } else {
       app.showPage(app.pages.HomePage);
    }

    loader.resumeLoad();
  },
  failure: function() {
    loader.resumeLoad();
    // your fallback code goes here
  }
});
```

If profile is absolute must, I would also recommend to enforce the check in onAttach event for every page but CreateProfile (to prevent navigation by direct link):

```js
// Profile datasource should be already loaded by startup script
// when onAttach event is fired
if (app.datasources.Profile.item === null) {
  throw new Error('Invalid operation!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking the user profile upon login. If the profile is not present, display the profile form, otherwise, proceed to the regular site.